# Unknown authentication strategy Passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I want to have 2 different instances of passport Js for my app (user and admin - both with jwt authentification ). I read in the official documentation that the way to distinguish between them is to name them.

What am I missing? Am i missing an export or something ?

```js
var Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    passport_authorised = new Passport();
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
const opts ={}
require('dotenv').config();

const databaseServiceAdmins = require('../../services/database_service_admin')
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer')

opts.secretOrKey = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET


passport_authorised.use("admin-rule",new JwtStrategy(opts,async function (jwt_payload, done) {
    const doesUserExists = await databaseServiceAdmins.adminExists(jwt_payload.email)

    if (doesUserExists.success === true && jwt_payload.access_rights === "privileged")
        done(null, doesUserExists.item)
    else
        done(null, false)

}));
```

```js
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const adminDatabaseService = require('../../services/database_service_admin')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const {callback} = require("pg/lib/native/query");
const passport_authorised = require("passport");
require('../json_authorisation/passport_authorised')
const {approvePtoRequestByAdmin, dropOnePtoDay} = require("../../services/database_service_admin");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

router.get("/all/not-approved",passport_authorised.authenticate("admin-rule",{session:false},callback),
    async (req,res)=>{
        const aux = await adminDatabaseService.getAllNotApprovedPtos()

        return res.status(200).send(
            aux
        )
    })
module.exports = router;
```

Error is:

> Error: Unknown authentication strategy "admin-rule" at attempt
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:193:39)
> at authenticate
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:370:7)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at
> /home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)
> at next
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle
> (/home/radu/Desktop/licenta/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question. I need help with it .

Comment: @radurbalau If instead of doing `new Passport()` you just do `const passport_authorised = require('passport')`, does the error still happen?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes i tried that way and i receive the same error

Comment: I mean, only once in your application `const passport_authorised = require('passport')`, then providing that same `passport_authorised` the file that has the route definition. An issue i can see is that they are two different variables across files, and perhaps where the `admin-rule` is registered, its not the same exact passport reference as where your route is defined. As in have a file that registers passport strategy under that name, then import that into where the route definition is used.

Comment: You could even try just registering a dummy route with `passport_authorised.authenticate('admin-rule'` in the same file as where the JwtStrategy is setup and see if the error still happens (commenting out the one in the other file)

Comment: Still the same issue, i figured a way to use only one type of passport.js jwt strategy that could do the admin and the user functionality in one object instead of having 2 different ones.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution, that being said I was able to accomplish this locally, so something else is going on locally with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having 2 JWT functionalities, one for admin and one for the unprivileged user, try to add in your JWT some roles (admin/user in our case). And sign the JWT with a secret key.

On a middleware when you decode JWT, validate it, and after check what role is in it. And allow/don't allow to pass.